# How to paging data in model level (django)

Tags: python, django, orm, pagination, paging

There is a `Paginator` in django. `from django.core.paginator import Paginator`.
But this Paginator need to get all data to feed it.
simple example:

```
def getMsgByPage():
    page =2

    messages = Message.objects.filter(participation__scene=scene, status='W')

    paginator = Paginator(messages , 50)

    page_obj = paginator.page(page)

    return page_obj
```

Every time a user view a page,I should get all messages to generate that.You know,It is very very bad when `messages table` contain huge data.

So,how can I page messages data in model level? Or I should create a paging stored procedure to do this? But django seems not support stored procedure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong. You are not passing the full set of messages to the paginator.

Querysets are lazy, and are not evaluated into they are iterated: in the case of the paginator, it will slice the object - which results in LIMIT/OFFSET being added to the SQL query before it is sent to the db. No more than a page of results will be fetched.

Comment: yeah,queryset will query database as little as possible:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy